# How to get the date for two saturdays ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which displays a table with date:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Db].[dbo].[btotals]
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Which displays:

```
Date
06/07/2014
05/31/2014
05/24/2014
05/17/2014
05/10/2014
05/03/2014
```

If I pick SELECT TOP 1 will give me the first row. How can I modify my query so I get the week prior to last week? In this case the `5/31/14` row?

Comment: Are you only storing dates for Saturdays?

Comment: Yes pretty much it's the date I am using for week ending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dates are always a week apart, and you just want the second row you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT  Date
FROM    (   SELECT  Date,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date DESC)
            FROM    [Db].[dbo].[btotals]
        ) AS d
WHERE   d.RowNumber = 2;
```

Otherwise you can use the following to get the saturday of 2 weeks ago:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) - 7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

Then select your first date that is on or after that:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 Date
FROM    [Db].[dbo].[btotals]
WHERE   Date >= DATEADD(DAY, -((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) - 7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
ORDER BY Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, if you are trying to select the second date, Though Gareth's approach of using `ROW_NUNMBER` is a better one.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 2 *
    FROM [Db].[dbo].[btotals]
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
) as X 
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [Db].[dbo].[btotals]
WHERE [Date] < (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [Db].[dbo].[btotals])
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```